# Disable buttons after click until post back of ascx control using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ascx

The page works as expected, disables the buttons and shows my loading indicator but the OnClick event is never called. I am relatively inexperienced with Javascript and I cannot seem to find an answer as to why this doesn't work.

I expect that once the Disable() method occurs and returns true it will call the OnClick method, which will cause a post back and automatically re-enable the buttons.

Perhaps I am going at this all wrong, I appreciate your help.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ComponentArt" Namespace="ComponentArt.Web.UI" Assembly="ComponentArt.Web.UI" %>
<%@ Control Language="c#" Inherits="MyControl"
Codebehind="ThisControl.ascx.cs"%>

<div class="Form" style="width: 100%">

  <img id="imgLoading" src="images/GridImages/spinner.gif" style="display:none" alt="loading..." />

  <ol>
    <li>
        <asp:Button ID="FirstButton" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="First Press Me"
            OnClick="First_Click" OnClientClick="this.value='Please Wait...'; needToConfirm=false; return Disable(); "/>
        <span>
            <asp:Button ID="SecondButton" CssClass="btn" runat="server" Text="Second Press Me"
                OnClick="Second_Click" OnClientClick="this.value='Please Wait...'; needToConfirm=false; return Disable(); "/>
        </span> 
    </li>
  </ol>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Disable() {
        document.getElementById('<%=FirstButton.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('<%=SecondButton.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        setTimeout('UpdateImg()', 0);
        return true;
    }
    function UpdateImg() {
        $('#imgLoading').show();
        var img = document.getElementById('imgLoading');
        img.src = 'images/GridImages/spinner.gif';
    }
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: when do you want the button to be disabled and when it is to be enabled??

Comment: @amarnath-balasubramanian, I want both buttons to be disabled upon clicking either until the post back occurs (i.e. the work has been completed)

Comment: When the post back happens mean, your code has been executed for a button click. Then why again you want to disable? If you want to disable, do it `button.Enabled=false` in the server side button click that you are executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://encosia.com/disable-a-button-control-during-postback/).

Added the "UseSubmitBehavior = False", and voila, the OnClick event was properly called.

Apparently asp immediately respects the disabling of the button and causes the event fire to fail.